# принципы ООП или код не должен повторяться

Tags: java, ооп

Сейчас изучаю Java и усваиваю главные принципы ООП, хочу избежать повторяющегося однотипного кода. Ниже я привел простой пример считывания данных с поля по нажатию кнопки, и указания ему (полю) неких правил. Эти правила могут повторятся для множества полей, и я не понимаю как можно создать некий класс с проверкой для любого поля, что бы в дальнейшем не прописывать одно и то же, а просто вызвать метод, где естественно заранее все правила будут указаны. Я конечно могу создать класс, и начать прописывать правила, но какому объекту их передавать или как это делается, ведь я не могу просто в методе сразу прописывать `getText().trim().contains("@")`и тому подобное. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться заблудшей душе.

```
 registrationButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        String passwordText = passwordRegField.getText().trim();
        String mailText = mailRegField.getText().trim();
        if (!passwordText.equals("") && !mailText.equals("") && mailText.contains("@") && mailText.contains(".")) {
            signUpNewUser();
        } else System.out.println("введите данные");
    });
```

Comment: `boolean isFoo(String mailText) { mailText= mailText.trim(); return !mailText.equals("") && mailText.contains("@") && mailText.contains("."); }` и `if (!passwordText.equals("") && isFoo(mailText)) {`?

Comment: я не до конца понимаю, что это. Я так понимаю это создание метода для той же проверки, но я его же не могу использовать постоянно для любого поля

Comment: В метод передаете значение, а не поле, соответственно, этот метод применим для любого вашего аналогичного поля

Comment: @gil9red понял, это же элементарно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызываете метод и передаете в него значения, а уже в самом методе они обрабатываются:

```
 registrationButton.setOnAction(event -> {

            String passwordText = passwordRegField.getText().trim();
            String mailText = mailRegField.getText().trim();
            your_method(passwordText, mailText );

        });

void your_method(String passwordText, String mailText) {

        if (!passwordText.equals("") && !mailText.equals("") &&
                mailText.contains("@") && mailText.contains(".")) {

            signUpNewUser();
        } else {
            System.out.println("введите данные");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

На Вашем месте я бы никуда не выносил методы, которые проверяют на то, что в строке что-то есть, а вот если логика сложнее, то использовал бы либо метод, либо если эта валидация применима ко многим классам, то вынес бы эту проверку в какой-нибудь утилитный класс в статический метод. И для проверки email использовал бы какое-нибудь подходящее регулярное выражение. 
public static boolean isValidEmail(final String value) {
    return value != null && value.matches(EMAIL_REGEXP);
}

Comment: Только утилитный класс со статическими методами это не ООП подход.

Comment: Я соглашусь с Вами, но чистый ООП подход не всегда применим. Можно создать интерфейс Validator и для каждого типа проверки реализовать свой конкретный  валидатор и передавать строку каждый раз конкретному объекту. Это уже будет более ОО, но стоит ли создавать столько объектов, когда можно дёрнуть статический метод. ИМХО.

Comment: да, вполне, излишняя абстракция может может запутать код, просто в каждом случае нужно думать, что лучше подходит